# How to access /data/data/ path of android in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an app in Android and there only one module is from Unity. I am downloading all data from server and save it in path with the method returns below.

getFilesDir().getPath()

Now in Unity, I want to get a json file from the directory and load the image in unity. But I am unable to get /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME from unity. Instead of that I am getting /Storage/Emulated/0/Android/data.I am using Application.persistentdata to get Android path. How to get /data/data path in Android. Please help me to resolve this. I am trying this for more than a week.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on something exactly like this and for me, it's working properly. The steps are:

1. Get the image path. The Application.persistentdata is exactly what you need.
2. Know beforehand the name of the file/image you want to access with its extension also (for e.g. - fish.png / manifest.json).
3. Add the file/image name to the image path right before accessing it through WWW call.

These steps will suit your need. Let me know if you get any problem in any of the aforementioned steps.

Comment: I am downloading images from server and save it in data/data/Package_name/files but from unity i am getting path as storage/emulated/0/Android/data. so i am getting file not exists in path. Because the path which unity points is different

Comment: @ParvathiM If you know your data path, then use the same path in place of Application.persistentdata path. Actually, I'm not exactly getting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact path that should be read, why don't you read the file with normal methods?

```
using System;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data/data/.../a.txt");
string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

However if you know the file's path in only Java side, then you can comminicate between Java and C# codes using `UnitySendMessage`, or `AndroidJavaObject` etc..

Comment: Hi, even if we hard code the path and put all files in rooted mobile, but still i m getting the error could not find the path.

Comment: How do you download files from the server. Is it in java side of your game? If so, just post the path that's been used in Java code, to C# side. If java can access the path to download and save any file, C# must also be able access this path to read file.